# how to fetch data in javascript from asp.cs method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i have following code how to bind grid using Java script i want to call aspx.cs code and retrieve data and bind with grid without post-back please help me. i am new asp.net please help me. i have call this method but not success

```js
       <script type='text/javascript'>


                          $(document).ready(function () {

                              bindjs();

                          })

                          function bindjs() {

                              PageMethods.BindGrid(Success, Failure);
                          }
                          function Success(result) {
                              alert(result);
                          }
                          function Failure(error) {
                              alert(error);
                          }
</script>
```

and my Asp.cs method is

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static  DataTable BindGrid()
    {

        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select tblStudent.student_id,tblStudent.student_name,tblStudent.father_name," +
            "tblStudent.Cell,tblStudent.parents_cell,tblStudent.admission_date,tblclassinfo.class_name,address_student" +
            " from tblStudent  inner join tblclassinfo on tblStudent.class_id =  tblclassinfo.class_id", con);



        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;

    }
```

Comment: are you using url: "http://localhost:54913/pages/studentinformation.aspx" like wcf for you?

Comment: no its webform page i want call method asp.cs method

Comment: ahh ok, so you dont have call any post on your javascript , only you have set public your method and access from javascript, or trt this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/calling-server-side-function-from-javascript-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: how to bind grid with javascript code

Comment: the best mode is using ajax wcf enabled with c# , in this case once defined your webservice and method you can access via javascript and with jquery or custom dom render your grid http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/ajax-enabled-wcf-service/

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the cs class to be inherited from

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

And then you method as follows

```
<WebMethod()> _
void BindGrid(string bookingInformation) {

    //your code here

}
```